# cant send mail through contact form in yahoo small business server. Do i need any configurations done before the program like smtp?

Tags: php

I want to host the form in yahoo small business server. Do I have to configure anything else other then coding in the hosting? New to the webhosting. 
i know the program works good but it shows error because i think there is no proper connection.

please to help.

**send_contact.php**

```
<?php

// Contact subject
$subject ="$subject"; 

// Details
$message="$detail";

// Mail of sender
$mail_from="$customer_mail"; 

// From 
$header="from: $name <$mail_from>";

// Enter your email address
$to ='';
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've received your information"
if($send_contact){
echo "We've received your contact information";
}
else {
echo "ERROR"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Obvious question, but I assume that $to actually has a value and that you only left it blank for posting to SO, right?

Comment: Found this at yahoo: http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&y=PROD_YSB_WH&locale=en_US&id=SLN20671&actp=lorax&pir=7HthGQlibUlfPalRk9tbOEXwzlWdqV6ynVEdNQ--

Comment: robbert - thanks for the reply..i actually filled it out..just for posting it here , i took the mail off..it din work even with that.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo requires you to do some setting up before you can send mail via PHP. All of the steps are detailed here:

https://help.yahoo.com/kb/yahoo-web-hosting/SLN20671.html?impressions=true